# SQL Statement to return previous quarter balance

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to create a query that can return the previous quarter balance for a series of records.

I have financial data for accountid (acctid), fiscal year (fyear), fiscal quarter (fquarter) and fiscal period (fperiod) that I'm summing and tracking through a series of other queries that I'm dropping in to a temporary table, that data includes the net change for the period (nperiod), net change for the quarter (nquarter) and net change for the year (nyear). Net change for the period is only the account transactions in the period, net change for the quarter is the cumulative total of the transactions that appear in periods 1-3, 4-6, 7-9 and 10-12 respectively (amount from previous periods are not calculated in proceeding quarters, ie the net change for the quarter resets to $0 for periods 4, 7 and 9) and the net change for the year is the total cumulative sum. I'm now trying to create a sql statement that returns the previous quarter end balance.

So for periods 1-3 I need to write a separate select statements to return the ending balance for the previous year, for periods 4-6 I want them ALL to return the net change for the quarter from period 3, for 7-9 I want to return the net change for the quarter from period 6 for all records and for period 10-12 I want to return net change for the quarter from period 9.

Can I get some assistance because I have a gigantic query that returns the max period per quarter, then the nquarter amount associated with that period and then trying to do a where exists, but something tells me there's a better way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: imo, essential information for someone to assist: Tables with sample data that we can use directly (DML and insert statements). Your current query? Especially if you have a query with a lot of code? We need to see what your current query is before trying to change it?

Comment: Try using nested subqueries. I'm not sure which DB system you are using (SQL Server? MySQL?), and you have left out some much needed information, but I like using nested subqueries for just this type of information. So you would essentially come up with (forgive the terrible syntax): `SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(NetAmount) FROM tbl WHERE accountid = tbl2.accountid AND fperiod = (tbl2.fperiod - 1)) AS LastPeriodAmount FROM tbl AS tbl2`

Comment: My bad ... SQL Server and here's the statement I could use to update the temp table ... just seems a bit clunky (also the logic doesn't work for period 1 since you need to pull the closing balance from the previous year and i'm only story 1 year of data in the temp table at a time ... i'll write a separate statement to get that balance, hence the CFR_I.RPTQ <> 1)

Comment: SELECT 
   CFR_O.ACCTID,
   CFR_O.RPTY,
   CFR_O.RPTQ,
   CFR_T.NCQ
  FROM 
   (
   SELECT
    CFR_I.ACCTID,
    CFR_I.RPTY,
    MAX(CFR_I.RPTP) RPTP,
    CFR_I.RPTQ
   FROM
    #tbl_CFR CFR_I
   WHERE 
    CFR_I.RPTQ <> 1 
   GROUP BY
    CFR_I.ACCTID,
    CFR_I.RPTY,
    CFR_I.RPTQ
   ) CFR_O
    INNER JOIN
   #tbl_CFR CFR_T
    ON CFR_O.ACCTID  = CFR_T.ACCTID AND
     CFR_T.RPTY = CFR_O.RPTY AND
     CFR_T.RPTP = CFR_O.RPTP AND
     CFR_T.RPTQ = CFR_O.RPTQ

Comment: Don't add code in comments [edit] your question. also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?